# Inner Join list of DataFrames on Row Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes in python pandas that have the same rowname and rowvalues. What I would like to do is produce one dataframe with them innerjoined on the rowvalues. I have looked online and found the merge function, but this isn't working because my rows aren't a column. Does anyone know the best way to do this? Is the solution to take the row values and turn it into a column, and if so how do you do that? Thanks for the help.

input:

```
          "happy"   
userid     
   1         2       
   2         8        
   3         9

          "sad"
userid
   1        9
   2        12
   3        11
```

output:

```
           "sad"   "happy"
userid
   1         9        2
   2         12       8
   3         11       9
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of your DataFrames? Also, it would be helpful if you posted what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: updated with expected input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your DataFrames have indices, in which case your `merge()` should indicate that's how it wants to proceed:

```
In [51]: df1
Out[51]:
        "happy"
userid
1             2
2             8
3             9

In [52]: df2
Out[52]:
        "sad"
userid
1           9
2          12
3          11

In [53]: pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[53]:
        "sad"  "happy"
userid
1           9        2
2          12        8
3          11        9
```

And if you want to run this over a list of DataFrames, just [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) them:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, left_index=True, right_index=True), list_of_dfs)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Transposing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) swaps the columns and rows of the DataFrame. If `dfs` is your list of DataFrames, then:

```
dfs = [df.T for df in dfs]
```

will make `dfs` a list of transposed DataFrames.

Then to merge:

```
merged = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
    merged = pd.merge(merged, df, how='inner')
```

By default [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) merges DataFrames based on all columns shared in common.

---

Note that transposing requires copying all the data in the original DataFrame into a new DataFrame. It would be more efficient to build the DataFrame in the correct (transposed) format from the beginning (if possible), rather than fixing it later by transposing.